# Getting 'port already in use error' when adding socket.io to express app - happens on any port I try

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, port

As stated in the title, I'm getting 'address already in use error' when trying to add socket.io to an existing express app.

It happens on every port so the only thing I can think of is it's trying to set port 8000 twice. I don't see where, however.

Here is the error in the console.
[image]

Here is my config.js

```
module.exports = {
PORT: process.env.PORT || 8000,
NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
DATABASE_URL: process.env.DATABASE_URL || 'postgresql://postgres@localhost/quik'
}
```

.env

```
NODE_ENV=development
PORT=8000
```

And here is my main express app. I've tried setting PORT from process.env and directly with '8000'.

```
require('dotenv').config()
const morgan = require('morgan')
const cors = require('cors')
const helmet = require('helmet')
const { NODE_ENV } = require('./config')
const userRouter = require('./user/user_router')
const pinsRouter = require('./pins/pins_router')
const chatRouter = require('./chat/chat_router')
const config = require('./config')

var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
io.on('connection', function(socket){
socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
io.emit('chat message', msg);
});
});

http.listen(config.PORT, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:8000');
});



const morganOption = (NODE_ENV === 'production')
  ? 'tiny'
  : 'common';

app.use(morgan(morganOption))
app.use(helmet())
app.use(cors())

app.use('/user_route', userRouter)
app.use('/pins_route', pinsRouter)
app.use('/chat_route', chatRouter)

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello, world!')
 })

app.use(function errorHandler(error, req, res, next) {
    let response
        if (NODE_ENV === 'production') {
            response = { error: { message: 'server error' } }
        } else {
            console.error(error)
            response = { message: error.message, error }
        }
    res.status(500).json(response)
    })

module.exports = app
```

Comment: kill the server once by this command `killall -9 node`

Comment: You probably haven't stopped the previous instance of your server.  It's still running so you can't start a new server on the same port.

Comment: @kedarsedai killall -9 node gives back ' no matching processes were found'

Comment: @jfriend00 are you saying the server could be running independent of port?

Comment: No.  I'm saying that the error message you see indicates that something is already running on port 8000.

Comment: Actually, the details of the error message make it look like you may also have another line of code in your same program that is trying to start another instance.  Do you have an `app.listen()` somewhere in another file?

Comment: Strangely I was getting the error on every port. I changed http.listen to port '3002' bc it said so online. Not sure why, but it seems to be working now.

Comment: The stack trace in the error appears like you are calling `app.listen()` somewhere (probably from your `server.js` - line 13).  You need to go find that code and remove it.

Comment: oh you're right, somehow I haven't been seeing that I have a server.js file for the last 3.5 hours

Comment: Appreciate the help, I would have never seen that in the error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack trace in the error appears like you are calling `app.listen()` somewhere (probably from your `server.js` - line 13). You need to go find that code and remove it.  You only want to attempt to start your same server once and your `http.listen()` is already starting it once.